# Obtener nombre de model dentro de appServiceProvider

Tags: php, laravel-5, mvc, controller

Estoy buscando cómo obtener el nombre del modelo dentro de un "provider", estoy usando este código ($this->model), pero no funciona

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
$vendedores = Vendedores::where('vendedores.Estado', 1)
            ->applyWhereLike()
            ->select('vendedores.*')
            ->paginate(40);
```

Comment: Que yo sepa los *providers* cargan cosas durante el arranque del framework, no veo como vas a tener acceso a un modelo sin una referencia directa al mismo. Puede que debas replantearte lo que estas haciendo o explicarlo con más detalle en la pregunta.